# how to access an element of a struct pointed by a void* in a second struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, void

I am having problems with a void* to struct. My C++ code is as follows:

```
struct BUFF_TYPE {
    int a;
    int b;
};
typedef struct BUFF_TYPE BUFF_TYPE;

struct REG_TYPE {
    int c;
    void *buff;
};
typedef struct REG_TYPE REG_TYPE;

REG_TYPE regs[20];
const BUFF_TYPE b_A = {3,5};


void func_x() {
    int x,y;
    regs[4].buff = (BUFF_TYPE*)&b_A;
    x = regs[4].buff->a;
    y = regs[4].buff->b;
}
```

It gives me:

```
error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
```

in x and y assignments, could you please tell me how to access those a and b values?

BTW, I need the void* as sometimes I need to point to other kinds of buffers.

Comment: You need to post the exact code that you're compiling. The code you originally posted has several typos. (I've fixed it.) Also, the `typedef`s are unnecessary in C++; if you declare a type `struct BUFF_TYPE`, you can refer to it as just `BUFF_TYPE`. (This is different in C.)

Comment: Consider carefully whether you *really* need `buff` to point to other kinds of buffers. You're probably better off defining a single type for `buff` to point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using ->, you must cast regs[4].buff to BUFF_TYPE*, so you need:

((BUFF_TYPE*) regs[4].buff)->a

Comment: Great! this was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `void*` type, but rather a `BUFF_TYPE*`.

If you need `void*` for ome other reason (unlikely based n your code), you can solve this by casting the pointer.

```
x = ((BUFF_TYPE*)regs[4].buff)->a;
y = ((BUFF_TYPE*)regs[4].buff)->b;
```

Comment: That will attempt to cast `regs[4].buff->b` to `BUFF_TYPE*`, which won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `void* buff` member of the `REG_TYPE` struct to a `BUFF_TYPE*` before dereferencing it.

Comment: To the downvoter how does this answer differ from either the OP accepted answer or the currently highest rated answer here?